# Bash command: ls -lah not showing /etc directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, ls

Ok guys, elementary question.

I was poking around my server, and I noticed that when I 'ls' the / directory, /etc folder is not displayed.  Why is that?  I can very easily cd into it, but why is it not displaying when I'm getting a list of those directories?

Note:
I'm using 'ls -lah'
list, all, human-readable.  The 'all' is showing me all directories, even hidden ones. 
Does the /etc folder have a different property to it that others do not?

Comment: look closer or post the exact output. `sudo apt-get install pastebinit` then `ls -lah | pastebinit` and post the url here.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably just missing it in the list. Try just `ls -lh` and see what you can find. Remember, too, that they're in alphabetical order, so it should be pretty easy to find.

If you still can't find it, post a screenshot of what you do see.